# Where can I find free Esperanto audiobooks?

Tags: literature, resources

With audiobooks, we can enjoy the literature in Esperanto handfree and anywhere. Where can I find some of them?

Comment: There was a site that had recordings of a few selections from *Fabeloj de Andersen*, they were very good quality, but now I can't find them :-(.

Comment: Ho, mi trovis ĝin!

Comment: This discussion is pretty interesting: http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/19382/2

Answer (score 8):

The only one I could find after some searching is https://librivox.org/la-aventuroj-de-alicio-en-mirlando-by-lewis-carroll/

Answer (score 8):

Here you can listen to [La Eta Princo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGS_uCAAwSQ) by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry.

If you want to download it and listen to it offline, I would recommend something like [AllTube Download](http://www.alltubedownload.net/) and select Audio only (mp3).

Comment: Ĝi bedaŭrinde estas legata kun tro unutona prononco, iom endormiga laŭ mi.

Answer (score 7):

You can get some of Jack Vance's works in mp3 format for free from [here](http://esperanto.us/indekso_JV.html). See the section "Scienca Fikcio", some of the entries there have an mp3 link. You can listen to them online or download them.

Answer (score 6):

Here are four selections from *Fabeloj de Andersen* ([link](http://www.kunlaboro.pro.br/esperanto/fabeloj/)); only the four under ***Fabeloj kun Voĉo*** have sound, the rest are just text. There are some others on [LibriVox](http://librivox.org/fabeloj-by-hans-christian-andersen/), but the pronunciation isn't very good. Like sometimes pronouncing "c" as "k" and stuff.

On the other hand, the LibriVox reading of *Alicio en Mirlando*, linked in another answer, is well-done and quite pleasant to listen to.

Looks like most of the rest of the [Esperanto material](https://librivox.org/search?primary_key=20&search_category=language&search_page=1&search_form=get_results) on LibriVox is individual selections from multilingual poetry collections, and some other bits of this and that. One of these days I'll get a computer that doesn't drown out my voice with its CPU fan, and then I can help get more recordings out there...

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Vikipedio listo](https://eo.wikibooks.org/wiki/Katalogo_de_Esperanta_retenhavo/Literaturo/Sonlibroj) with sonlibroj. There aren't a lot of resources, but there is a cute audiobook for kids.

As well as this [Chinese page](http://www.elerno.cn/audio/auskultado.htm) with a few things.

Answer (score 4):

The book "Gerda malaperis" can be listened to at http://lernu.net/de/biblioteko. You need a lernu.net account to access the library.

Answer (score 4):

[*LibriVox*](https://librivox.org/search?primary_key=20&search_category=language&search_page=1&search_form=get_results) currently has 20 free audiobooks you can download.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a short article about [audiobooks in Esperanto](http://enricbaltasar.com/audiolibros-esperanto/) with a compilation last year.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one I recorded yesterday. It’s a book of six Chinese folktales.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k_nyRLL-GWo